# Evitar que muestre duplicados en un array de imágenes en Android

Tags: android, array, random, android-imageview

Tengo un `array` de imágenes y las cuales las muestro en un `ImageView`.

```
int[] fotos={R.drawable.alacran, R.drawable.apache,R.drawable.arana,R.drawable.arbol,
                R.drawable.arpa, R.drawable.bandera,R.drawable.bandolon,R.drawable.barril,
                R.drawable.borracho, R.drawable.bota,R.drawable.botella,R.drawable.calavera};
```

....

El cual lo muestro de manera random:

```
final Random ran=new Random();
        int i=ran.nextInt(fotos.length);
        image.setImageResource(photos[i]);

        image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
             int k=ran.nextInt(fotos.length);
             image.setImageResource(fotos[k]);
            }
        });
```

Hasta ahí va bien, se muestran las imágenes. Pero me gustaría saber como evito que se repitan algunas, por ejemplo si son 15 imágenes que las vaya mostrando aleatoriamente sin repetir y cuando se muestren las 15 manda algún mensaje que ya se han terminado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes barajar de manera aleatoria la lista con [Collections.shuffle](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/collections_shuffle.htm) y recorrer sus indices de manera ordenada.

Creas una variable `index` de tipo `int`, global:

```
private int index = 0;
```

Con tu Array `photos`, lo conviertes a `List<int>` para poder utilizar el método shuffle:

```
List<int> shuffledList = new ArrayList<int>(Arrays.asList(photos));
```

Y en tu metodo `onClick`, reordenas la lista cuando comience el indice, si llega al final, muestras un mensaje. Por ejemplo:

```
image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(index == 0)
                   Collections.shuffle(shuffledList);

                if(index == shuffledList.size()){
                   // Aqui lanzas un Toast, diciendo que llegaste al final
                  //index = 0; // Si descomentas esta linea, comenzara a mostrar las imágenes en un nuevo orden con cada click
                }
                 else{
                    image.setImageResource(shuffledList.get(index));
                    index++;
                 }


            }
        });
```

Si quieres mostrar una primera imagen antes de dar `click` y seguir el algoritmo en secuencia, después de hacer el `setOnClickListener`, escribe el siguiente código:

```
image.performClick();
```

Comment: si funciona, ya no muestra repetidos, una pregunta, y como le hago para que no lleve ese orden, es decir, que sea aleatorio?

Comment: @megaonly a que te refieres con que no lleve ese orden?. La logica de este algoritmo, es que desordenes la lista y despues la recorras. Es decir, Shuffle lo que hace es barajar una lista, poniendo un orden aleatorio de sus elementos, en vez de usar la logica del indice random que es como lo estabas haciendo que a veces se repetia un mismo numero aleatorio. Shuffle desordena la lista con la misma probabilidad para todos sus elementos, haciendo que su orden sea completamente aleatorio. Ya solo recorres la lista aleatoria, con sus indices en orden.

Comment: Te lo decía ya que a como está ahora, recorre el array de forma ordenada, tal cual están las imágenes, es decir va mostrando las imágenes exactamente como está el array, de forma ordenada y no aleatoriamente, solo cambiala pimera imagen y el resto sigue ordenado, gracias.

Comment: @megaonly ah, ya vi el error, lo que pasa es que no es `fotos[indice]`, sino, `shuffledList.get(indice)`. Ya actualice el código.

Comment: Te agradezco tu ayuda, pero sabes, me hace exactamente lo mismo, recorre el array de forma ordenada y no aleatoria, solo primera si cambia.

Comment: @megaonly, asi deberia funcionar. Puedes editar tu codigo en tu pregunta, como lo tienes ahora para yo probarlo?

Comment: Perdón, no me había fijado que estaba empleando otra función aparte que evitaba eso. ya quedó muchas gracias!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Para esto puedes convertir el array de enteros a list y usar este método:

```
        //Elimina elementos duplicados.
        Set<Integer> hs = new HashSet<>();
        hs.addAll(intList);
        intList.clear();
        intList.addAll(hs);
```

al final la lista de elementos enteros tendría únicamente los no repetidos.

Este sería el código completo:

```
 int[] fotos={R.drawable.alacran, R.drawable.apache,R.drawable.arana,R.drawable.arbol,
            R.drawable.arpa, R.drawable.bandera,R.drawable.bandolon,R.drawable.barril,R.drawable.borracho,R.drawable.bota,R.drawable.botella,R.drawable.calavera};

        //Convierte array de enteros a list<Integer>.
        List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i : fotos)
        {
            intList.add(i);
        }
        //Elimina elementos duplicados.
        Set<Integer> hs = new HashSet<>();
        hs.addAll(intList);
        intList.clear();
        intList.addAll(hs);

        //al final tienes una lista intList, que no incluye elementos repetidos
        //Puedes verificar el resultado de esta forma:
        for (int i : intList)
        {
            System.out.println("elemento: " + i);
        }
```